# Can I disable an address link in HTML?

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I have the following:

```
<a href="/Product/Overview">Overview</a>
<a href="/Product/Review">Review</a>
```

When I am on the overview page I want to make it so that clicking the overview address link does nothing. Something like disable for a button. Is this possible for an address link?

Comment: if you are referring to asp.net mvc, checkout this: http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<a href="/Product/Overview" onclick="return false;">Overview</a>
```

Of interest may also be [nofollow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow):

```
<a href="/Product/Overview" onclick="return false;" rel="nofollow">Overview</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to disable a link is probably to remove the href value.

If you are rendering this from MVC, simply don't include the `<a>` tag.

It's a little unclear what is best for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Arbitrarily removing the `href` attribute may have SEO consequences.

Comment: Did you down vote me for that? Just about any way of disabling a link could potentially have SEO consequences. Link crawlers are getting more and more sophisticated at detecting non-working links, and there's nothing particularly difficult about detecting a link blocked by JavaScript. Moreover, the OP never said anything about SEO concerns. Could be a private site for all I know. And sites routinely render text as non-links when clicking them wouldn't make any sense. Sheesh!

Comment: It's late (didn't see this comment until now), but FWIW, I did not downvote you.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'return false' to prevent linking:

```
<a href="/Product/Overview" onclick="return false">Overview</a>
```

Comment: Don't know why this was down-voted after being up-voted, this is a valid solution.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a `#` sign in the `href` like so: `<a href="#">Overview</a>`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? In the follow up question, he using this in his solution?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but using # instead of the actual URL could prevent search engine crawlers from properly indexing the site hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with a layer of javascript on top of each page: your JS script would run and check all the links on the page -- if the link is the same as the page you are on then simply "hijack" the anchor by adding an `onclick` event which does nothing and doesn't bubble up the event.
This was you still pump out from your server side all the links -- and the script would be the same for all the pages, thus allowing it to be cached by the browser and only loaded once (assuming you place it in an external `.js` file).

Answer (score -1):

You can try `<a class="inactive" href="#">Overview</a>` and give it some CSS to show it's a different type of link.